# Redirecting back to my custom tab page's iframe app after auth

Tags: facebook, authentication, redirect

I've got an app embedded in an iframe in a 520px wide custom tab page of my fanpage.

When it auths a user, it always takes them to the full-width canvas page for the app rather than the custom tab page. How can I resolve this please? It's driving me nuts!

Pete

Comment: Have you tried to change the `redirect_uri` to the Page tab?

Comment: Hiya! Oddly enough that's what I did in the end and it worked, albeit I'd tried that several times already. Thanks for getting back to me though!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your `redirect_uri` to your Page Tab url.